# Negative of an image in lua/torch

Tags: image-processing, lua, torch

How can I obtain the negative of an image using lua/torch? I want to do this to double the size of my training set for a machine learning project.

Answer (score 1):

image.load returns images with a range of [0,1], so here's the code to flip the image to a negative image:

```
require 'image';
a=image.lena()
a:add(-1):abs();
```